# “Terminal” would like to access files in your Desktop folder

Tags: terminal, macos, sonoma

I'm getting the following prompt *after each reboot*:

`“Terminal” would like to access files in your Desktop folder`

[image]

Is there any way to set it once for all pls?

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.1.2
BuildVersion:       23B92
```

Comment: Either remove whatever is in your shell startup files that tries to get to ~/Desktop, or give Terminal Full Disk Access.